# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null - possible syntax error

Tags: javascript, html

Working on a simple Tic Tac Toe game to better my JS but am stuck with this error msg. My "console.log("message");" returns what it should display " Game is ready. Player X turn." Its a single file with my script tags at the end just above my `</body>` tag. It's pretty basic. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var Display = function(displayElement) {      // create 'class' to eliminate many 'innerText' usage 
 var display = displayElement;        // and makes it easy to port to say android
 function setText(message) {
  console.log(message);
  display.innerText = message;
 }

 return {setMessage: setText};
};

 function isValid(button) {          //if text within then not valid; if 0 then valid; any 
  return button.innerText.length == 0;      //characters then invalid
 }

 function checkForWinner(squares, players, currentTurn) {
  if (squares[0].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[1].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[2].innerText == players[currentTurn])
   return true;
  if (squares[3].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[4].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[5].innerText == players[currentTurn])
   return true;
  if (squares[6].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[7].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[8].innerText == players[currentTurn])
   return true;
  if (squares[0].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[3].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[6].innerText == players[currentTurn])
   return true;
  if (squares[1].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[4].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[7].innerText == players[currentTurn])
   return true;
  if (squares[2].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[5].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[8].innerText == players[currentTurn])
   return true;
  if (squares[0].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[4].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[8].innerText == players[currentTurn])
   return true;
  if (squares[2].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[4].innerText == players[currentTurn] &&
   squares[6].innerText == players[currentTurn])
   return true;
 }

 function setMark(button, mark) {
  button.innerText = mark;
 }

 function main() {
  var squares = document.querySelectorAll("#game button"); // returns array of all the buttons
  var players = ["X", "O"];         // text displayed in the button
  var currentTurn = 0;           // either will be 0 or 1
  var isGameOver = false;          // boolean either T or F
  var display = new Display(document.querySelector("gameActionDisplay")); //reference to msg      

  display.setMessage("Game is ready. Player " + players[currentTurn] + " turn.");

  for (var i = 0, len = squares.length; i<len; i++) {   //for loop to iterate through squares; set local var len
   squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (isGameOver)
     return;

    if(!isValid(this)) {
     display.setMessage("Invalid move bud!");
    } else {
     setMark(this, players[currentTurn]);

     isGameOver = checkForWinner(squares, players, currentTurn);

     //Game is over

     //Game is draw

     //Game is not over yet; play on
     currentTurn++;         // mod remainder toggles between 1 and 0    
     currentTurn = currentTurn % 2;

     display.setMessage("Player " + players[currentTurn] + " move");

    }
   });
  }
 }

 main();
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="game">
   <div>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
   </div>
   <div>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
   </div>
   <div>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
   </div>

   <div id="gameActionDisplay"></div>


 </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Within your constructor function Display. You execute return {setMessage: setText}; - ignoring setText uses param.

Comment: @AndrewLi : DOM is ready as script tags are at the bottom of the body, no JQuery is used. Did you actually review question and the code before voting down my question?

Comment: @LANole Don't assume I voted down your question... I *didn't* in fact, vote it down...

Answer (score 2):

you need you get your element by id

```
document.querySelector("#gameActionDisplay")
```

do the trick

Cheers

Comment: Ugh... the damn '#'. I spent WAY too long going over this code and never saw that was missing. That did it. Think its time to give my eyes a rest. Many thanks.